# Как получить картинку их аудиофайла в java?

Tags: java, android-studio

Хочу сделать плеер и вот пытаюсь выловить картинку из mp3 файла. Пытался установить mp3agic и с помощью него извлечь, но при установки вылезают ошибки. Так же хотел через класс `MediaMetadataRetriever`, но знаю, как подобраться к файлу. В общем, жду помощи))

Comment: Может быть я чего-то не знаю, но в аудиофайлах хранят звуки, а не изображения.

Comment: Значит и правда мало знаете)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобраться к файлу может помочь метод [getEmbeddedPicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getEmbeddedPicture()):

```
metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);
byte[] cover = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
if (cover != null) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cover, 0, cover.length);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(songImage);
}
```

Или [getPrimaryImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getPrimaryImage()), если API level позволяет.